# getting attribute via xpath query succesfull in browser, but not in Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, svg, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a certain XPATH-query which I use to get the height from a certain HTML-element which returns me perfectly the desired value when I execute it in Chrome via the XPath Helper-plugin.

```
//*/div[@class="BarChart"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect" and @class="bar bar1"]/@height
```

However, when I use the same query via the Get Element Attribute-keyword in the Robot Framework

```
Get Element Attribute//*/div[@class="BarChart"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect" and @class="bar bar1"]/@height
```

... then I got an InvalidSelectorException about this XPATH.

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'invalid selector: Unable to locate an 
element with the xpath expression `//*/div[@class="BarChart"]/*[name()="svg"]/*
[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect" and @class="bar bar1"]/`
```

So, the Robot Framework or Selenium removed the @-sign and everything after it. I thought it was an escape -problem and added and removed some slashes before the @height, but unsuccessful. I also tried to encapsulate the result of this query in the string()-command but this was also unsuccessful.

Does somebody has an idea to prevent my XPATH-query from getting broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't include the attribute axis in the XPath itself when you're using Robot. You need to retrieve the element by XPath, and then specify the attribute name outside that. It seems like the syntax is something like this:

```
 Get Element Attribute xpath=(//*/div[@class="BarChart"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect" and @class="bar bar1"])@height
```

or perhaps (I've never used Robot):

```
 Get Element Attribute xpath=(//*/div[@class="BarChart"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect" and @class="bar bar1"])[1]@height
```

[This documentation](http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.7#Get%20Element%20Attribute) says

> > attribute_locator consists of element locator followed by an @ sign and attribute name, for example "element_id@class".

so I think what I've posted above is on the right track.

Comment: Hi JLRishe, that was exactly the solution I was looking for. I knew about this prefix to XPATH-queries in the Robot Framework, but it's often not needed to place it. Most of my XPATH-queries which I use work fine without, but this one needs it.

Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Your original attempt might have worked if you just remove the `/` before `@height`. The error message you got seems to suggest that too (it thinks the `/` before `@height` is part of your element selector).

Comment: No, that didn't work, That was one of the things I tried. Moreover, I found several examples online that even said to use this / -sign.

Comment: @JLRishe Can you please look into my problem and solve me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189178/match-an-element-with-a-dynamic-attribute-value

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your observation that the keyword seems to removes everything after the final `@`. More correctly, it uses the `@` to separate the element locator from the attribute name, and does this by splitting the string at that final `@` character.

No amount of escaping will solve the problem as the code isn't doing any parsing at this point. This is the exact code (as of this writing...) that performs that operation:

```
def _parse_attribute_locator(self, attribute_locator):
    parts = attribute_locator.rpartition('@')
    ...
```

The simple solution is to drop that trailing slash, so your xpath will look like this:

```
//*/div[@class="BarChart"]/... and @class="bar bar1"]@height`
```